# What are the benefits of using HTML description lists (dl, dt, dd)?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dl) explains the `<dl>`,`<dt>` and `<dd>` tags can be used to implement a glossary or a list of key-value pairs.

According to [maxdesign.com.au](http://maxdesign.com.au/articles/definition/) (article posted in 2004, its statings may be inaccurate) there are even  downsides in using them:

- The `<dt>` within definition lists cannot contain block level elements;
- Search engines will not index definition list content "in the same way" that they do for heading-based content;
- They cannot contain screen reader accessibility features such as “labels” and “headers” to tie information together.

Moreover, their basic browser-out-of-the-box styling is replicated with minimal effort while omitting the above described downsides.

Are there any **tangible** benefits (in terms of semantics, SEO, etc.) of using HTML description lists over tables, paragraphs, or perhaps any other element?

Comment: it's helpful to Boost SEO and Accessibility for you website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> - The `<dt>` within definition lists cannot contain block level elements;

Untrue - `<dt>`s can contain some block level elements, such as paragraphs.

> - Search engines will not index definition list content "in the same way" that they do for heading-based content;

So what? Not in the same way does not mean better or worse. Typically, in a well written page headings *should* score higher than definition terms or descriptions.

> - They cannot contain screen reader accessibility features such as “labels” and “headers” to tie information together.

Mostly untrue. `<dt>` can't contain headers. `<dd>` can. Both can contain labels (although it would be pretty weird to want to have one in a `<dt>`).

> Are there any tangible benefits (in terms of semantics, SEO, etc.) of using HTML description lists over tables, paragraphs, or perhaps any other element?

`<dt>`s automatically get the "term" role for accessibility tools to use.
`<dd>`s automatically get the "definition" role for accessibility tools to use.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think the accessibility argument is a strong but often overlooked one.